# DNS works only after I ping it

Tags: macos, dns, vpn, ping

Actual problem is that I open VPN (OpenVPN) connection to my office on my mac.

This connection changes my preference to a new DNS (in office). I cannot visit any page until I manually ping dns by IP. After that everything works like a charm (until VPN disconnected, of course).

I really do not understand this behavior, but I am sure I can solve this because my colleagues (with Macs too) have no problems with this. Please, give me any hint how this can be fixed.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using DHCP. Before you ping, what DNS server are you pointed at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to flush the local DNS cache on your Mac:

dscacheutil -flushcache

Or maybe your local router onsite needs to flush it's DNS cache, especially if your mac is set up so that the local router is the gateway.

Before connecting, check your IP, gateway, and DNS, then connect (but don't do the ping thing yet), repeat, and then ping, and finally check again.

If this isn't illuminating, log into the local router's admin interface and do similar steps to the above.

Comment: Looks like you're right - I can't say what exactly helped, but now DNS is picking up correctly.